# Get power state when Android app starts

Tags: android

How to know if the power is connected or not when my application is starting ?

I know, that I can get power state using broadcast receiver with `ACTION_POWER_CONECTED` and `ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED` but when my app is starting I do not received these Broadcasts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't actually have to register a receiver when calling `registerReceiver` ;-). Run

```
Intent intent = registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
```

It will return the last intent that has been broadcasted for the given filter. From `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED`, you can determine whether the phone is on battery or connected to a power source:

```
bool isOnBattery = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1) > 0
```